# Copy data from cells in sheet1 to different non-continuous columns in sheet2 with google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In a google spreadsheet document I have two sheets, one called BD Products and another called Add product.

The first sheet (BD Products) is a table with all the information of the products (by rows). Some cells contain formulas to make calculations automatically. Other cells are empty fields that must be filled in by hand. To do this, I have created a form on the "Add product" sheet where there are those empty fields on the first sheet that are to be filled in manually.

My intention is to send that data from the form of the "Add product" sheet to the "BD Products" sheet when clicking on the submit button. The problem is that these data must be copied in different non-continuous columns.

To give you an example;

SKU field of the Add product form is in cell D10, in the BD Products sheet the SKU field is in column E.

CATEGORIA field of the Add product form is in cell H10, in the BD Products sheet the CATEGORIA field is in column D.

NOMBRE PRODUCTO field of the Add Product form is in cell D12, in the BD Products sheet, the NOMBRE PRODUCTO field is in column C.

PVP field of the Add product form is in cell E14, in the BD Products sheet the PVP field is in column Z.

% DESPERDICIO field of the Add product form is in cell D19, in the BD Products sheet the % DESPERDICIO field is in column M.

And so on continuously.

As you can see, in the BD Products sheet there are columns in between that do not have fields to fill in in the form of the Add Product sheet because they are columns that contain formulas that make automatic calculations.

In addition to that, I would like the form data of the "Add Product" sheet to be copied one row after the last occupied row of the BD Products sheet (which I do with the getLasRow () + 1).

How can you do that? I don't think she's the only one in such a situation ...

I've been looking for information on how to do it on YouTube, Google, and here on Stackoverflow, but I just can't find information about it.

It is worth mentioning that I am a total novice and it is my first code.

The code that I have done so far is the following:

```
function Enviar4() {

  const libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const hojaOrigen = libro.getActiveSheet();
  const hojaDestino = libro.getSheetByName('BD Productos');

  var NombreProducto = hojaOrigen.getRange('D12').getValue();
  var Categoria = hojaOrigen.getRange('H10').getValue();
  var Sku = hojaOrigen.getRange('D10').getValue();
  var DesperdicioMaterial = hojaOrigen.getRange('D19').getValue();
  var MargenBeneficio = hojaOrigen.getRange('H19').getValue();
  var IvaMayorista = hojaOrigen.getRange('D24').getValue();
  var IvaClienteFinal = hojaOrigen.getRange('H24').getValue();
  var PvpClienteFinal = hojaOrigen.getRange('E14').getValue();


  var producto = [[NombreProducto,Categoria,Sku,DesperdicioMaterial,MargenBeneficio,IvaMayorista,IvaClienteFinal,PvpClienteFinal]]

  const rangoDestino = hojaDestino.getRange(hojaDestino.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, hojaDestino.getLastColumn());

  rangoDestino.setValues(producto);

  spreadsheet.getRangeList(['D10', 'H10', 'D12', 'E14', 'D19', 'H19', 'D24', 'H24']).clearContent();

}
```

I also attach screenshots:

Add product: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oKUGJsgomxNa2mCSn9e6GJq78JmmpIcf/view?usp=sharing

BD Products: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CQjfUQSgpIMhoUbTvfKY4ELMpWOO4Dk5/view?usp=sharing

Can someone help me with the code please? Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

Somehow get to achieve it with the following code.
Now my question is is there any way to simplify this a bit more?

```
function Enviar6() {

var libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 

var hojaOrigen = libro.getSheetByName("Añadir producto");
var hojaDestino = libro.getSheetByName("BD Productos");

hojaOrigen.getRange("D12").copyTo(hojaDestino.getRange(hojaDestino.getLastRow()+1,3,1,1,), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
hojaOrigen.getRange("H10").copyTo(hojaDestino.getRange(hojaDestino.getLastRow(),4,1,1,), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
hojaOrigen.getRange("D10").copyTo(hojaDestino.getRange(hojaDestino.getLastRow(),5,1,1,), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
hojaOrigen.getRange("D19").copyTo(hojaDestino.getRange(hojaDestino.getLastRow(),13,1,1,), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
hojaOrigen.getRange("H19").copyTo(hojaDestino.getRange(hojaDestino.getLastRow(),15,1,1,), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
hojaOrigen.getRange("D24").copyTo(hojaDestino.getRange(hojaDestino.getLastRow(),18,1,1,), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
hojaOrigen.getRange("H24").copyTo(hojaDestino.getRange(hojaDestino.getLastRow(),23,1,1,), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
hojaOrigen.getRange("E14").copyTo(hojaDestino.getRange(hojaDestino.getLastRow(),26,1,1,), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

//Vaciar las celdas del formulario "Añadir producto" después de envíar los datos a la "BD Productos"
 hojaOrigen.getRangeList(['D10', 'H10', 'D12', 'E14', 'D19', 'H19', 'D24', 'H24']).clearContent();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to modify your script to the simpler script.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp) is used. At first, an object is prepared for copying the values, and the values are copied using the object in a loop.

#### Modified script:

```
function Enviar6() {
  var libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var hojaOrigen = libro.getSheetByName("Añadir producto");
  var hojaDestino = libro.getSheetByName("BD Productos");
  var row = hojaDestino.getLastRow() + 1;
  var obj = [
    { src: "D12", dst: "C" + row },
    { src: "H10", dst: "D" + row },
    { src: "D10", dst: "E" + row },
    { src: "D19", dst: "M" + row },
    { src: "H19", dst: "O" + row },
    { src: "D24", dst: "R" + row },
    { src: "H24", dst: "W" + row },
    { src: "E14", dst: "Z" + row },
  ];
  obj.forEach(({src, dst}) => hojaOrigen.getRange(src).copyTo(hojaDestino.getRange(dst), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false));
  hojaOrigen.getRangeList(['D10', 'H10', 'D12', 'E14', 'D19', 'H19', 'D24', 'H24']).clearContent();
}
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, Sheets API is used. At first, an object is prepared for copying the values, and the values are copied using the object with Sheets API. Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

In this case, the values are retrieved from the scattered cells by one API call, and the retrieved values are put to the scattered cells by one API call. I thought that the process cost of this pattern might be a bit lower than that of pattern 1.

#### Modified script:

```
function Enviar6() {
  var libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var hojaOrigen = libro.getSheetByName("Añadir producto");
  var hojaDestino = libro.getSheetByName("BD Productos");
  var row = hojaDestino.getLastRow() + 1;
  var obj = [
    { src: "D12", dst: "C" + row },
    { src: "H10", dst: "D" + row },
    { src: "D10", dst: "E" + row },
    { src: "D19", dst: "M" + row },
    { src: "H19", dst: "O" + row },
    { src: "D24", dst: "R" + row },
    { src: "H24", dst: "W" + row },
    { src: "E14", dst: "Z" + row },
  ];
  var id = libro.getId();
  var values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet(id, { ranges: obj.map(({ src }) => `'Añadir producto'!${src}`) });
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate({ valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED", data: obj.map(({ dst }, i) => ({ range: `'BD Productos'!${dst}`, values: values.valueRanges[i].values })) }, id);
  hojaOrigen.getRangeList(['D10', 'H10', 'D12', 'E14', 'D19', 'H19', 'D24', 'H24']).clearContent();
}
```

### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)

Comment: Thank you very much for all your explanation! I will take the time to test it and understand all the code. Your help is greatly appreciated! Report the result later. Thank you! :)

Comment: I have tested the code and it works perfectly!

In fact, the sequence when getting active is even much faster than with the code that I formed!

Now in half a second the form is sent and the data copied. Before, with my code, it took like 4 seconds.

I am happy to have been able to learn a little more about it and to have been able to count on your help.

Thank you very much! :D

Comment: @Nerea Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.